# Added file in hard drives in this pc via regedit and now cannot remove it

Tags: windows-10, regedit

I found [this tutorial](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/add-custom-folder-this-pc-navigation-pane-windows/) on how to pin my folders to this pc.
I don't know how but I created a file under my hard drives and I don't know how to remove because I lost the file where I've written my GUID and my backup copys of the registry so I'm unable to find it. I know that the DescriptionID could be 0, 1, or 2 to be listed in my hard drives.
[Here is an image of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzJu8.png)
When I click on it I can see only "Cut-Create link-Delete" context menu.
Can someone tell me a way to remove it with regedit?